# Table caption alignment with respect to table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How to align table caption in following example to the left of table (instead of being centered) ? Unfortunately I cannot find any switch which would govern this. Command

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedleft}
```

does nothing.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Prilohy}
    \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{minipage}{16cm}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \ttabbox[\FBwidth]        
    {\caption{Zoznam slavnych cinskych basnikov podla Kroebera -- tabulkova forma}}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        Poradie & Meno & Alternativny \newline prepis mena & Koeficient \newline vynimocnosti & Rok \newline narodenia \\ \hline
        1 & Shi-King & & & \\ \hline
        2 & Ch'ü Yüan & Qu Yuan & 2 & -332 \\ \hline
        3 & Sung Yü & Song Yu & & \\ \hline
        4 & King Tsz'e & & & \\ \hline
        5 & Kiah I & & & -199 \\ \hline
        6 & Chuang-ki & & & \\ \hline
        7 & Huai-nan-tze & & & -122 \\ \hline
        8 & Tung-fang So & Dongfang Shuo & & -160 \\ \hline
        9 & Liu Hsiang & & & -80 \\ \hline
        10 & Liu Heng & & & -157 \\ \hline
        11 & Mei Sheng & & 2 & -140 \\ \hline
        12 & Ssu-ma Siang-ju & & & -121,5 \\ \hline
        13 & Princezná Si-kiün & & & \\ \hline
        14 & Cisár Liu Ch'ê alebo Wu Ti & & & \\ \hline
        15 & Hsü Kan & & & \\ \hline
        16 & K'ung Jung \newline (alebo Ying) & & & \\ \hline
        17 & Wang Ts'an & & & 177 \\ \hline
        18 & Yin Yang & & & \\ \hline
        19 & Lin Cheng & & & \\ \hline
        20 & Ch'en Lin & & & \\ \hline        
        21 & Yüan Yü & & & \\ \hline
        22 & Ts'ao Ts'ao & & & \\ \hline
        23 & Ts'ao Chih & & & \\ \hline
        24 & Liu Ling & & & \\ \hline
        25 & Hsi (Ki) K'ang & & & \\ \hline
        26 & Hsiang Hsiu & & & \\ \hline
        27 & Yüan Hsien & & & \\ \hline
        28 & Yüan Chi & & & \\ \hline
        29 & Wang Jung & & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

P.S. Recommended solution

```
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
```

does nothing. Also take in mind that page margins are in my case narrower by 1cm is not standard.

[image]

Comment: Use `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}`

Comment: \captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off} does nothing.

Comment: It does for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MdC2x.png Are you loading `caption` package?

Comment: After loading caption package all is OK. But I don't understand why the latex compiler did not finish with error (like the C++ did if I omit some include) ?

Comment: After thoroughly checking your solution it could be seen that first letter of caption "T" is a few pixels more to the left than left border of table.

Comment: Please... a picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: The link is above in Harish Kumar comment.

Comment: @truthseeker: I have an improvelment of your table with `tabularx`and a few other packages, but cannot post it any more. Is there a link where I could upload it if you're interested?

Comment: @truthseeker: How do I do that from here?

Comment: I updated my profile recently with my email address.